# How to stream video file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In asp  .net I want to create page which should stream a video file and should not be downloaded
at client side
something similar to youtube video file

Comment: more like streaming video file

Answer (score 0):

Simply embed to the  tag url in html5